# How to apply my custom themes with ConfigProvider in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

We are developing a using interface with React and Ant Design. We would like to override the default theme and colors. As an example we defines an array called themes. There is 4 differents themes as object. I defined a button to change theme. Reading the official docs I have included the following code in App.js to override the default theme but no success.

```
ConfigProvider.config(
 {
  theme:theme
 }
)
```

Can anyone help me to override the default theme without less or anything else but just with ConfigProvider?

```
import "./App.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import ChangeTheme from "./components/ChangeTheme";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./_context";

const App = () => {
const { theme } = useContext(AppContext);
ConfigProvider.config({
theme: theme,
});
return (
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <ConfigProvider>
    <div className="App">
      <ChangeTheme />
    </div>
  </ConfigProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
);
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First Step**

you need to import `antd.variable.min.css` in one of your root files, like `src/index.js` which is recommended in the [document](https://ant.design/components/config-provider/#components-config-provider-demo-theme),

> import 'antd/dist/antd.variable.min.css';

**Second Step**

you also need to import antd's `ConfigProvider` in `src/index.js`:

> import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';

**Third Step**

then you need to modify the theme variables in `config` method of `ConfigProvider` like below:

> ConfigProvider.config({ theme: { primaryColor: "#f00" } });

**ps** the vriables that you can modify in `theme` are:

- primaryColor
- errorColor
- infoColor
- processingColor
- successColor
- warningColor

**Fourth Step**

finally you wrap `ConfigProvider` around the `<App/>` component in `src/index.js`

```
<ConfigProvider>
    {/* some other codes you might have */}
    <App />
</ConfigProvider>
```

Comment: Is the same steps to be follow if we are using less?

Comment: @AariefMohideen you can use anything you want beside it, because it's only java-script code, and its not related to your style-sheets

Comment: thanks for the information Sima.I had a issue with dynamic color (primaryColor) update using ConfigProvide. Example: I have a color picker -> once selected color 1 (Green) -> updating primaryColor -> There is no reflection. If I have selected color 2 (Yellow) -> Now the primaryColor gets updated with color 1 (Green). I know this is not relevant with this question but may help some one. Thanks for advance

Comment: @AariefMohideen you are totally welcome, and I think the problem you mentioned is with the way you're handling state changes, setState() does not always immediately update the component, please have a look at [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) or post a new question and put your code in it, and we can solve it together

Comment: Where can I see complete list of variables available to modify?
@simaghoreyshi

Comment: @ChinmayAtrawalkar please have a look at this [url](https://ant.design/components/config-provider/), it's the official documents of ant design about config provider, at the bottom of the page is the list of all configurations possible